# How to make (image-filled) div that stretches when resizing page to be fixed size or stretched proportionally?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, frontend

Basically what I did so far is I got the basic layout of what I wanted. But the problem is, when I resize the page, the image-filled div (childInnerDiv left) also keeps morphing too. I want the profile div to essentially stay fixed or at least stretch proportionally. I think the issue is that I'm using flexbox, and it'll ultimately stretch... but I'm not sure how to create the layout without flexbox with the correct ratios. I used position: fixed, but that messes up the layouts.

There's also other issues of how I can't use anchor tags to link to other sites, I have to use css properties (background-image: url()). Also JSFiddle, made the UI look different too..

**What I Want:**
Note images are supposed to be circular which is not depicted below.
[image]

**Website UI (What I Have using React, HTML, CSS)**
[image]

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ad60k98n/53/
[image]

CSS

```
.ProjectsParentDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: max-width;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.childDiv {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 60%;
    height: 25%;
    margin: 5px auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.childInnerDiv {
    display: flex;
    height: 95%;
    z-index: 2;
}


.childInnerDiv.left {
    width: 15%; 
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 250ms;
}

.childInnerDiv.left:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.imageCoveringDiv {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


.childInnerDiv.right {
    height: 80%;
    width: 65%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    display: block;
}

.childInnerDiv span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* ChildInnerDiv(s) for images. */
#HorusDiv {
    background-image: url("Some Link");
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

#LH3000Div {
    background-image: url("Some Link");
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#RandomDiv {
    background-image: url("Some Link");
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ProjectsParentDiv">

  <div class="childDiv">
    <div class="childInnerDiv left" id="HorusDiv">
      <a href="Some Link">
        <img class="imageCoveringDiv" id="HorusImg" href="/client/src/Assets/horus.png" />
        Some Image
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="childInnerDiv right">
      <span class="DescriptionDiv">
        <b>Project 1:</b> Some Description
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="childDiv">
    <div class="childInnerDiv left" id="LH3000Div">
      <a href="Some Link">
        <img class="imageCoveringDiv" id="LH3000Img" href="/client/src/Assets/horus.png" />
        Some Image
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="childInnerDiv right">
      <span class="DescriptionDiv">
        <b>Project 2:</b> Some Description
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="childDiv">
    <div class="childInnerDiv left" id="RandomDiv">
      <a href="Some Link">
        <img class="imageCoveringDiv" id="RandomImg" href="/client/src/Assets/horus.png" />
        Some Image
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="childInnerDiv right">
      <span class="DescriptionDiv">
        <b>Project 3:</b> Some Description
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. and where is the height of 95%?
draw and write exactly what you want.

Comment: Imo you have a hammer called flexbox so every div you have is a nail... Try to only use flexbox when **necessary**, it'll make it easier to reason about your layout

Answer (score 1):

Just to make things work, I've added these properties:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
min-height: 100px;
min-width: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
max-width: 100px;
```

Hope it helps you move forward. https://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9t1ns2xe/

Comment: Thank you! I was also wondering if it was possible in flexbox to make the circles smaller and not touch the edges of the div?

Comment: Add a `padding`: https://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9t1ns2xe/2/